# Is there a way to enable intent's fulfillment using Dialogflow's Node.js library?

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es

How do I turn this on here using only the Dialogflow library and not manually?

[image: screenshot of options]

Comment: You can create an intent in fulfillment directly without using the interface

Comment: how? @Gray_Rhino

Comment: Here's the link to doc: https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/reference/rest/v2beta1/projects.agent.intents/create

Comment: I just needed to enable webhookstate in request. Thanks, solved it.